# British National Corpus

Tags: java, web-services, nlp

Has anyone used bnc (british national corpus) http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/ . Is there a way to query it from a java application?

Comment: though I think it would work as a good generic web service question.

Comment: The XML documentation is here. http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/docs/URG/

Comment: @driis. You should provide such references as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML documentation is here. http://natcorp.ox.ac.uk/docs/URG

Should be quite easy to parse in Java using your favourite XML parser. As long as you buy a copy of the BNC and adhere to the license you buy, I see no reason you cannot use it from Java.